# Web scraping to download documents with dropdown form

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape the World Health Organization website (https://www.who.int/publications/m) >> using the "**WHO document type**" dropdown for "**Press Briefing transcript**".

In the past Ive been able to use the following script to download all specified file types to the working directory, however I haven't been able to deal with the drop down properly.

```
# Working example 

library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

page <- read_html("https://www.github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets")

raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
  html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
  html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
  str_subset("\\.pdf") %>% # find those that end in pdf only
  str_c("https://www.github.com", .) %>% # prepend the website to the url
  map(read_html) %>% # take previously generated list of urls and read them
  map(html_node, "#raw-url") %>% # parse out the 'raw' url - the link for the download button
  map(html_attr, "href") %>% # return the set of raw urls for the download buttons
  str_c("https://www.github.com", .) %>% # prepend the website again to get a full url
  walk2(., basename(.), download.file, mode = "wb") # use purrr to download the pdf associated with each url to the current working directory
```

If I start with the below. What steps would I need to include to account for the "**WHO document type**" dropdown for "**Press Briefing transcript**" and DL all files to the working directory?

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rvest)
    library(stringr)

    page <- read_html("https://www.who.int/publications/m")

    raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
     html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
     html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
     str_subset("\\.pdf") %>% # find those that end in pdf only
     str_c("https://www.who.int", .) %>% # prepend the website to the url
     map(read_html) %>% # take previously generated list of urls and read them
     map(html_node, "#raw-url") %>% # parse out the 'raw' url - the link for the download button
     map(html_attr, "href") %>% # return the set of raw urls for the download buttons
     str_c("https://www.who.int", .) %>% # prepend the website again to get a full url
     walk2(., basename(.), download.file, mode = "wb") # use purrr to download the pdf associated   with each url to the current working directory
```

Currently, I get the following:

```
Error in .f(.x\[\[1L\]\], .y\[\[1L\]\], ...) : cannot open URL 'NA'
```

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rvest)
    library(stringr)

    page <- read_html("https://www.who.int/publications/m")

    raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
     html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
     html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
     str_subset("\\.pdf") %>% # find those that end in pdf only
     str_c("https://www.who.int", .) %>% # prepend the website to the url
     map(read_html) %>% # take previously generated list of urls and read them
     map(html_node, "#raw-url") %>% # parse out the 'raw' url - the link for the download button
     map(html_attr, "href") %>% # return the set of raw urls for the download buttons
     str_c("https://www.who.int", .) %>% # prepend the website again to get a full url
     walk2(., basename(.), download.file, mode = "wb") # use purrr to download the pdf associated with each url to the current working directory
```

Results
PDFs downloaded to working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much to do with rvest, that document list is not included in the page's source (that rvest could access) but pulled by javascript that is executed by the browser (and rvest can't do that). Though you can make those same calls yourself:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# get list of reports, partial API documentation can be found 
# at https://www.who.int/api/hubs/meetingreports/sfhelp
# additional parameters (i.e. select & filter) recovered from who.int web requests 
# skip: number of articles to skip
get_reports <- function(skip = 0){
  read_json(URLencode(paste0("https://www.who.int/api/hubs/meetingreports?",
                             "$select=TrimmedTitle,PublicationDateAndTime,DownloadUrl,Tag&",
                             "$filter=meetingreporttypes/any(x:x eq f6c6ebea-eada-4dcb-bd5e-d107a357a59b)&",
                             "$orderby=PublicationDateAndTime desc&",
                             "$count=true&",
                             "$top=100&",
                             "$skip=", skip
                             )), simplifyVector = T) %>% 
    pluck("value") %>% 
    tibble()
}
# make 2 requests to collect all current (164) reports ("...&skip=0", "...&skip=100") 
report_urls <- map_dfr(c(0,100), ~ get_reports(.x))
report_urls
#> # A tibble: 164 × 4
#>    PublicationDateAndTime TrimmedTitle                             Downl…¹ Tag  
#>    <chr>                  <chr>                                    <chr>   <chr>
#>  1 2023-01-24T19:00:00Z   Virtual Press conference on global heal… https:… Pres…
#>  2 2023-01-11T16:00:00Z   Virtual Press conference on global heal… https:… Pres…
#>  3 2023-01-04T16:00:00Z   Virtual Press conference on global heal… https:… Pres…
#>  4 2022-12-21T16:00:00Z   Virtual Press conference on global heal… https:… Pres…
#>  5 2022-12-02T16:00:00Z   Virtual Press conference on global heal… https:… Pres…
#>  6 2022-11-16T16:00:00Z   COVID-19, Monkeypox & Other Global Heal… https:… Pres…
#>  7 2022-11-10T22:00:00Z   WHO press conference on global health i… https:… Pres…
#>  8 2022-10-19T21:00:00Z   WHO press conference on global health i… https:… Pres…
#>  9 2022-10-19T21:00:00Z   WHO press conference on global health i… https:… Pres…
#> 10 2022-10-12T21:00:00Z   WHO press conference on COVID-19, monke… https:… Pres…
#> # … with 154 more rows, and abbreviated variable name ¹​DownloadUrl

# get 1st 3 transcripts, for destfiles plit url by "?", take the 1st part, use basename to extract file name from url
walk(report_urls$DownloadUrl[1:3], 
     ~ download.file(
       url = .x, 
       destfile = basename(str_split_i(.x, "\\?", 1)),mode = "wb"))

# str_split_i() requires stringr >= 1.5.0, feel free to replace with:
# destfile = basename(str_split(.x, "\\?")[[1]][1]),mode = "wb"))

# list downloaded files
list.files(pattern = "press.*pdf")
#> [1] "who-virtual-press-conference-on-global-health-issues-11-jan-2023.pdf"
#> [2] "virtual-press-conference-on-global-health-issues-24-january-2023.pdf"
#> [3] "virtual-press-conference-on-global-health-issues_4-january-2023.pdf"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

That "working example" in question comes from https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-downloading-and-storing-pdfs-in-r-367a0a6d9199 , it is rather difficult to take and apply anything from that article unless you are already familiar with everything written there. To understand why applying scraping logic built for one site almost never works for another, maybe check https://rvest.tidyverse.org/articles/rvest.html & https://r4ds.hadley.nz/webscraping.html (both from rvest author).

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with str_split_i , with the error                                         
Error in str_split_i(.x, "\\?", 1) : could not find function "str_split_i", which is preventing the DL's coming in as pdfs. Im working on a mac, but not sure whats throwing this off. Any ideas?

Comment: This comes from stringr 1.5.0 - https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/12/stringr-1-5-0/#splitting, there has been a stream of Tidyverse updates lately. You can replace it with `destfile = basename(str_split(.x, "\\?")[[1]][1]),mode = "wb"))` , added a note to answer comments.